# Association with columnPrefix giving SQLException invalid column name

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

I'm getting `SQLException: invalid column name` when trying to use an `<association>` tag with `columnPrefix`. e.g.

Example Result Maps:

```
<resultMap id="foo" type="Foo">
  <result column="col1" property="col1"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap ...>
  <association property="myFoo" 
               notNullColumn="some_id"
               resultMap="foo"
               columnPrefix="BAR_"/>
</resultMap>
```

Example SQL:

```
select some_id, BAR_col1, ... from (someTables)
                ^^^^--prefixed columns...
```

If I take `columnPrefix` off and make a custom resultmap of `foo` that has `bar_` embedded for each column, it works. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `notNullColumn`! It must follow two rules:

- In the SQL statement, the column alias must start with the column prefix (so `select BAR_some_id ...`) even if it's not part of the associated result map (`foo`, in my case).
- The `notNullColumn` declaration should not include the prefix. (so `notNullColumn="BAR_some_id"` is wrong. It has to be `notNullColumn="some_id"`.)